# Creating multiple linked lists in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Hi I’m having a bit of trouble with some C programming. I’m trying to make multiple linked lists of class names.

I’ve currently got:

```
struct class_list {
    char name[20];
    struct class_list *next;
} *class;

class setup_new() {
    class start;
    *start = NULL;
    start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
    if (start == NULL)
        printf("error");
    return start;
}
```

But it its working and I cant figure out why.

Comment: What about it isn't working? What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: Ideally, you would use a name other than `class` for this struct pointer because that's a reserved keyword in C++ and may confuse people.

Comment: Is there a hidden typedef?  Using a typedef for a struct is a bad idea, and not including the typedef in your question is even worse.

Comment: @jarmod but this is a C question, therefore `class` is perfectly legal.

Comment: @WilliamPursell -   _"Using a typedef for a struct is a bad idea"_, maybe for  `struct` being used for linked lists, but too strong a statement to be used as a general statement about   `typedef struct`

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
struct class_list {
  char name[20];
  struct class_list* next;
};

struct class_list *setup_new() {
  struct class_list *start;
  // this is wrong and pointless: *start = NULL;
  start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
  if (start == NULL)
    printf("error");
  return start;
}
```

Or maybe this which is basically the same:

```
typedef struct class_list {
  char name[20];
  struct class_list* next;
} class;

class *setup_new() {
  class *start;
  // this is wrong and pointless: *start = NULL;
  start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
  if (start == NULL)
    printf("error");
  return start;
}
```

or maybe even this:

```
typedef struct class_list {
  char name[20];
  struct class_list* next;
} *class;

class setup_new() {
  class start;
  // this is wrong and pointless: *start = NULL;
  start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
  if (start == NULL)
    printf("error");
  return start;
}
```

I don't recommend the last possibility, because here we're hiding a pointer type behind a typedef which often causes confusion.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- you define `class` as a global variable but use it as typedef, causing syntax errors.
- You dereference an uninitialized pointer `class` with `*start = NULL`. This has undefined behavior.

Note that it is more readable and less problematic to avoid C++ keywords as C identifiers and to avoid hiding pointers behind typedefs.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct class_list {
    char name[20];
    struct class_list *next;
} *class_head;

struct class_list *setup_new(void) {
    struct class_list *start = malloc(sizeof(*start));
    if (start == NULL)
        printf("error\n");
    return start;
}
```